# Picard's Existence and Uniqueness Theorem finding an interval for the IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Determine the contants and the largest interval such that the solution of the IVP exist and unique on rectangular area.
> $i-)\; x^{\prime}=x^2, \; x(0)=1,\;R=\{(t,x):|t|\leq2,\;|x-1|\leq2\}$.

Let $f(t,x)=x^2\;$ and  $$\;|f(t,x)|=|x^2|\leq9=L$$ The function satisfying the Lipschitz Condition on R, since;

$$\left|\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|=|2x|\leq6$$
So,

$$h=\min\left(a,\frac{b}{L}\right)=\min\left(2,\frac{2}{9}\right)=\frac{2}{9}$$

Hence, the largest interval is;

$$\left|t-0\right|\leq h=\frac{2}{9} \rightarrow -\frac{2}{9}\leq t \leq \frac{2}{9}$$

Such that the solution of IVP exist and unique on R

Is it true? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually in this context it is $M$ for a bound on the function value and $L$ for a Lipschitz constant. You can compute the exact solution via separation, this in most cases will give a larger interval for the solution remaining inside the box.

Comment: In my textbook (The Textbook of Ordinary Differential Equations, Deo, Lakshmikantham, Raghavendra) L is used for bound and K is used for Lipschitz, I am a stranger of this notation too but I finally get used to this notation. But my question is for Picard's theorem does my solution make sense?

Comment: Okay, if we explicitly solve then we get $x=\dfrac{1}{1-t}$ then we have: $(-\infty,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ so what should I choose? Either sets doesn't include $0$ then how could we solve the IVP?

Comment: You have $-\infty<0<1$, so the selection of the domain should be obvious. // Then yes, keep to your immediate notation conventions. // Your solution is correct as application of the standard construction in the proof of the P-L theorem. One easy improvement is to observe that $x$ has to remain positive for this IVP solution, which gives stricter bounds on the function value. But that is, one could say, a second iteration of the theorem, using its uniqueness claim to improve the proof construction for this specific case.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a clarification!